# Interrupt routine in Arduino library never called

Tags: arduino, interrupt

I am trying to write an Arduino library that uses an interrupt routine. Everything seems OK, no compilation error is thrown, but it does not work, as the `isr` routine is never called.

In this simplified version the `while` loop runs forever, despite the correct interrupt trigger being fired. If I test this outside the library, it works without problems.

What may be wrong here?

Library code:

```
class test {
  public:
    int read(int clockPin);
    volatile unsigned long called;
}

volatile unsigned long called=0;

static void isr() {
  called++;
}

int test::read(int clockPin) {
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(clockPin), reinterpret_cast<void (*)()>(&isr), FALLING);
  // or attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(clockPin), isr, FALLING);
  // none of them raise an error but it does not work
  while (called==0) { delay(1); }
  detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(clockPin));
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: You may want to check this code: https://github.com/moozzyk/ArduinoDigitalClock/blob/master/src/DigitalClock.pde#L211-L244. It is setting a timer interrupt.

Comment: I think I see the error. There are probably 2 "called" variables defined. A class and a non-class one. As the isr is defined as non-class here, it increments the non-class variable, but the read routine asks for the class one, which never gets incremented. So possibly the isr is really called, but does something different, than I thought it does :)